# SUM for previous Weeknum in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose we have a table

```
weeknum | revenue
------------------
12      | 10000
12      | 10000
12      | 10000
13      | 10000
13      | 10000
13      | 10000
14      | 10000
14      | 10000
```

I tried to calculate the sum of the revenue for the previous weeknum:

```
Previous Revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[revenue]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table1[weeknum]), 
    Table1[weeknum] = Table1[weeknum]-1
    )
    )
```

But, it is failed. Any Idea on this one

Answer (score 2):

The statement you are passing to `FILTER`'s *FilterExpression* needs to refer to the entry from `Table1[weeknum]` within the *current row context*.

This can be achieved by replacing

`Table1[weeknum] = Table1[weeknum]-1`

with

`Table1[weeknum] = MIN(Table1[weeknum])-1`

though it is perhaps better practice to create a *variable*, viz:

```
Previous Revenue :=
VAR ThisWeekNum =
    MIN( Table1[weeknum] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( Table1[revenue] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( Table1[weeknum] ),
            Table1[weeknum] = ThisWeekNum - 1
        )
    )
```